# Multiple Filter Queries with OR operation in Solr

Tags: solr

I need to define multiple Filter Queries in my query but with OR operation. 
Imagine that there are fq1, fq2 and fq3. Now I would like my final filter query to be :

fq=fq1 AND fq2 OR fq3

Is there any way to handle it in Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Solr.  It would be great if you could define your filter queries and then separately specify the boolean logic that should be applied between them.

A few years ago I created a [Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1223) hoping to see this get added.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that now SOLR (>4.5) supports these type of queries, i.e.

fq=(field1:value1 OR field2:value2)

Comment: According to the `fq` documentation for Solr 4.9, ["Filter queries can involve complicated Boolean queries."](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-Thefq%28FilterQuery%29Parameter), which argues that you are correct. Do you know of any examples you could link to?

Comment: I could not find any reference online that I cab cite. However, I tried it out in an application that I currently develop and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

`fq=fieldA:(valueA OR valueB) OR fieldB:valueC`

Answer (score -1):

```
+fq:fq1 +(fq2:fq2 fq3:fq3) <-- if default query filter type is OR
```

Comment: Are you sure this works?  I've been hoping for this feature for awhile, see here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1223

Comment: Soli, I'm thinking the same can be done by using the normal query (not the filter query)